# Filter out file using wildcard path azure data factory

Tags: filter, path, azure-data-factory

I am working on a pipeline and while using the copy activity,  in the file wildcard path I would like to skip a certain file and only copy the rest. Is there an expression for that ? I know that a * is used to match zero or more characters but in this case, I would like an expression to skip a certain file.

I am still very new to adf

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure you can use the wildcard feature to skip a specific file, unless all the other files follow a pattern the exception does not follow.

One approach would be to use GetMetadata to list the files:

[image]

Note the inclusion of the "ChildItems" field, this will list all the items (Folders and Files) in the directory.

Next, use a Filter activity to reference only the files:

[image]

Items code:

```
@activity('Get Child Items').output.childItems
```

Filter code:

```
@and(equals(item().type,'File'),endswith(item().name,'.txt'))
```

**NOTE:** This example filters to Files with a .txt extension. You would change this code to meet your criteria.

Finally, use a ForEach to loop over the now filtered items. The ForEach would contain our COPY activity for each individual item:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer . I am not sure why but this solution didnt work out for me , the filter doesnt passes zero items to the for each. However, I indeed only have one file that I would like to filter out so if there is an expression I can use in the wildcard file that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Very clear and helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: This worked great for me. Thank you for taking the time to document all that.

Answer (score 0):

In `Get Metadata` activity, we can add an expression to get files of a specific pattern. I tried to write an expression to exclude files but was not successful.

Below is what I have tried to exclude/skip a file from the list of files to process.

**Files in the Input folder:**

[image]

**Azure Data Factory Pipeline:**

1. In my Input folder, I have 2 types of files `.csv` and `.txt`. You can add expression in the filename to get the only “.csv” files using **Get Metadata** activity

Filename Expression: `*.csv`

[image]

**Get Metadata activity Output:**

[image]

2. Connect `filter` activity to `Get Metadata` activity output to exclude a file (or files of specific pattern) from the list of files from child items.

**Filter activity Settings:**

**Items:** `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems`

**Condition**: `@not(contains(item().name,'1c56d6s4s33s4_Sales_09112021.csv'))`

[image]

**Output of Filter activity:**

[image]

3. Process each value of filter activity using `foreach` activity.

**Items**: `@activity('Filter1').output.Value`

[image]

This loop runs 2 times as there are only 2 files that returned from filter activity output after excluding a file.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, wildcards don't seem to be supported by Get Metadata...?

Comment: have you created a dataset parameter for the source dataset?

Comment: Yeah, but my wildcard not only applies to the file name but also subfolders.

Comment: The answer provided is for the folder which contains only files and not subfolders. If you have a subfolder the process will be different based on your scenario.