# Azure Data Factory - How to filter out specific files in multiple Zip. files?

Tags: filter, azure-data-factory

I have set up a ADF pipeline that gets a set of .Zip files from Azure Storage, and iterates through each Zip file's folders and files to land them in an output container with preserved hierarchy.

**Get Metadata:**
[image]

**For Each:**
[image]

**Issue:**
The issue is that there is a specific .PDF file (ASC_NTS.pdf) that is embedded within each .Zip file that has the same name:

[image]

[image]

It is causing this error when trying to run the pipeline:

> Error
> Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed; Inner activity name: Copy data1, Error: ErrorCode=AdlsGen2OperationFailedConcurrentWrite,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when trying to upload a file. It's possible because you have multiple concurrent copy activities runs writing to the same file 'FAERS_output/ascii/ASC_NTS.pdf'. Check your ADF configuration.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'PreconditionFailed'. Account: 'asastgssuaefdbhdg2dbc4'. FileSystem: 'curated'. Path: 'FAERS_output/ascii/ASC_NTS.pdf'. ErrorCode: 'LeaseIdMissing'. Message: 'There is currently a lease on the resource and no lease ID was specified in the request.'. RequestId: 'b21022a6-b01f-0031-641a-453ab6000000'. TimeStamp: 'Thu, 31 Mar 2022 16:15:56 GMT'..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.Models.ErrorSchemaException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'PreconditionFailed',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Is there a workaround for this pipeline setup that allows me to filter within the For Each loop?  I just need the .TXT files, the .PDF files can be discarded.

This was the closest reference I could find, but does not address my use case:
[Filter out file using wildcard path azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287340/filter-out-file-using-wildcard-path-azure-data-factory)

Comment: You'll probably need to unzip the contents to an intermediate location, with a unique folder path name. Then use Get Metadata to identify the desired files and copy them to the final location. Then use Delete to discard the intermediate location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an If Condition activity? You can set the expression to check for the correct file extension.